# How can I check if the user would like animations (through the system setting for it)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winapi

I'd like to have animations in my program, but before I impose them on everyone (especially people with poor hardware) I'd also like to check if they are even desired.

So specifically I'd like to check the setting from the Performance Option window (screenshot below).

[image: Animate controls and elements inside windows setting]

I've noticed some programs making use of it (which is how I even know this exists) so I figure there must be an accessible API for it I could use.

So my question is simply how could I check if that setting is turned on or off?
Ultimately this goes in a C# WPF application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick you are looking for

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, out bool pvParam, uint fWinIni);

private static uint SPI_GETCLIENTAREAANIMATION = 0x1042;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        bool animationsEnabled;
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETCLIENTAREAANIMATION, 0x00, out animationsEnabled, 0x00);

        if (animationsEnabled)
        {
            //Animate controls and elements inside windows is checked
        }
        else
        {
            //Animate controls and elements inside windows is not checked
        }
    }
    catch (Win32Exception ex)
    {
        //error
    }
}
```